# UPDATE query with OUTPUT clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to write a query which would select all the rows from a table added or changed from the last time it was executed.

I have table `tbl` with **`datetime`** field `timechg`, which is set to `getdate()` when the row is INSERTed and every time is UPDATEd. The moment of the last execution of my query is stored in 1-row table `lastrun` in the field `ts`. The query is supposed to return the data and set `ts` field to `getdate()` at the same time. This is what I came up with:

```
UPDATE lr
   SET lr.ts = getdate()
OUTPUT t.*
  FROM lastrun lr
       INNER JOIN tbl t ON lr.ts < t.timechg
```

`ts` field is properly updated, but the query returns only one row (the one with the smallest `timechg` value). The query

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM lastrun lr
       INNER JOIN tbl t ON lr.ts < t.timechg
```

returns proper dataset.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why ore you outputting the values from `tbl ` (which isn't even the table you're inserting into)? *Normally* you would output the values from `inserted` and/or `deleted`.

Comment: You are out of luck. In order to `output` from one of the tables you are *not* updating, you will have to use the `merge` statement.

Comment: Your `UPDATE` is incorrect to begin with if you expect more than one row in the `OUTPUT`, as you would be non-deterministically updating a row multiple times. Even if you're using the same value every time, this is still a no-no. You are "in luck", because the engine de-duplicates the updates before that happens, but that also means your `OUTPUT` won't give more than one row regardless.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis No Luck --> `The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.`

Comment: Begin transaction, select (with `UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK` on `lr`), update, commit. I'm pretty sure (if not 100% sure) that you can't stuff all of this in one statement on SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong.  I don't see an `into` or `select` query to process the results.  Or a query to see what the values are.  I would expect:

```
-- Create an empty table to hold the results
create table #t as
    select lastrun.*
    from lastrun
    where 1 = 0;

UPDATE lr
   SET lr.ts = getdate()
   OUTPUT t.* INTO #t
   FROM lastrun lr JOIN
        tbl t
        ON lr.ts < t.timechg;

SELECT * FROM #t;
```

Comment: `OUTPUT` clause doesn't need always an `INTO` clause.

Comment: @Sami . . . Yes, but there should be an `insert` in the statement, if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below example code for Using OUTPUT clause during UPDATE Query.

```
if object_id('tempdb..#temp') is not null
drop table #temp

if object_id('tempdb..#Inserted') is not null
drop table #Inserted

create table #temp
(
id int,
ts datetime
)

insert into #temp
values (1,'2018-01-01 20:29:58.507')

--select * from #temp;

CREATE TABLE #Inserted
(   [inserted_ts] datetime,
    [deleted_ts] datetime,
)

update #temp 
set 
ts='2019-10-02 20:29:58.507' 
output deleted.ts AS [deleted_ts],inserted.ts AS [inserted_ts]
    INTO #Inserted
where id=1

--select * from #temp
select * from #Inserted
```